# Partial view not sending model in subdomain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, subdomain, partial-views

I have a MVC4 published in a subdomain.

Since I've published, partial views are not sending model changings to controller.

This is on .cshtml:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_PartialEmpreendimentos", "Empreendimentos", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "Resultados",
    LoadingElementId = "loader",
    OnSuccess = "setBusy"
},
new { @name = "FormPrincipal" }))
{
    @*<%-- Resultados --%>*@
    Html.RenderAction("_PartialEmpreendimentos", Model);
}
```

Here I have the controller:

```
public ActionResult _PartialEmpreendimentos(PesquisaEmpreendimentoDto pesquisa)
        {
            code here...

            return PartialView("_PartialEmpreendimentos", pesquisa);
        }
```

When access the action up here, the model is empty.

Any idea what can I do?

Here is the website from example:

http://dev.centure.com.br/dev/Empreendimentos/EmpreendimentosLista/

**The submit access the controller, but with a empty model**
**Work fine in localhost**

It's in a shared host, so the route insert "/dev/" in every action link.

**UPDATE**

Viewing the network sending the model was sent as well, with all parameters fine. That make me think that the problem is the response, not in calling of controller.

**UPDATE 2**

In network I'm receiving 302 code response. This make the page redirect to get action on controller, I think.

Please help, I'm desperate!

Comment: Did you tried by put a breakpoint on model. is both Model and value are in ActionResult are different ?

Comment: I can't put a breakpoint cause this only happens in published code. Like I said before, in localhost work fine.

Answer (score 0):

So, I couldn't resolve it.

I just published in a absolute domain, and so it is.

It seems there no way to use a shared host and keep things working fine.